# Customized priority function in DataStructure["PriorityQueue"]?

Tags: programming, built-in-symbols, data-structures

I'm using *Mathematica* 12.1. The documentation for [`DataStructure["PriorityQueue"]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/datastructure/PriorityQueue.html) claims that,

> ... the highest-priority element is always returned.

> The priority of two elements is determined by the `Order` function.

I'm wondering if I could use my own priority function with it, so I tried "overloading" the [`Order`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Order.html) function (semantically) like

```
With[{f = 20 - # &},
 Block[{Order = Order[f[#1], f[#2]] &},
  Module[{hp = CreateDataStructure["PriorityQueue"]},
   Scan[hp["Push", #] &, Range[20]];
   hp["Pop"]
   ]]]
```

but failed to change its behavior -- outcome is still 20 while 0 is expected.

Could this be achieved or one has to do the implementation by oneself since seemingly [`DataStructure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataStructure.html)s don't support functions like [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html)?

Comment: It seems to me that a custom ordering function would need to be contained in the data structure, to be used with every `"Push"` operation.  It seems chaotic to have an ad hoc `Order` behavior for each operation.  I suspect you are seeking functionality that isn't (yet) implemented.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes. So after posting the question I was thinking that, okay, we can't have an ad hoc `Order`'s behavior, but we can change what we pass to it! Then I seem able to answer my own question :-) Please contribute while there's room for improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the lead of your own workaround you might consider an abstraction like this:

```
pqpat = PQ : DataStructure["PriorityQueue", ___];

orderQueue[pqpat, ofn_]["Push", val_] := PQ["Push", {ofn@val, val}]
orderQueue[pqpat, ofn_]["Pop"] := PQ["Pop"][[2]]

hp = CreateDataStructure["PriorityQueue"];

foo = orderQueue[hp, 20 - # &];

Do[foo["Push", i], {i, 20}]

Table[foo["Pop"], {20}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
> ```

I'll leave it to you to implement the remaining methods.

Answer (score 4):

I just found that, when `Order` compares two lists, if their first elements are already unequal, the result is in effect the `Order` between them. So here is a solution I can come up with:

```
With[{f = 20 - # &},
 Module[{hp = CreateDataStructure["PriorityQueue"]},
  Scan[hp["Push", {f[#], #}] &, Range[20]];
  Table[hp["Pop"][[2]], 20]
 ]]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20} *)
```

You push data together with their priorities. When you pop, you need to discard the priority.

Other test:

```
With[{f = -RealAbs[# - 10] &}, (* Minimize |x-10| *)
 Module[{hp = CreateDataStructure["PriorityQueue"]},
  Scan[hp["Push", {f[#], #}] &, Range[20]];
  Table[hp["Pop"][[2]], 20]
 ]]
(* {10, 11, 9, 12, 8, 13, 7, 14, 6, 15, 5, 16, 4, 17, 3, 18, 2, 19, 1, 20} *)
```

Output is the same compared to

```
Reverse@SortBy[Range[20], -RealAbs[# - 10] &]
(* {10, 11, 9, 12, 8, 13, 7, 14, 6, 15, 5, 16, 4, 17, 3, 18, 2, 19, 1, 20} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numElements = 12;

(*
 Here is a way to reverse the order function i.e. 
 use**Order[#2, #1]** & for *ascending* and
 **Order[#1, #2] &** for *descending*.
*)

data = Table[ RandomInteger[1000], {i, numElements}];
pq = CreateDataStructure["PriorityQueue", data, Order[#2, #1] &];
Print["Pushed values = ", data];
For [i = 1, i <= numElements, i++, (
  impq = 
   Rasterize[pq["Visualization"], ImageSize -> Small, 
    ImageResolution -> 400];
  Print[impq];
  Print["Popped value = ", pq["Pop"]];
  )
 ]
```